# Unable to make calls to MobileFirst Platform server in preview

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I'm having problems debugging/previewing my app in any browser with the command *mfp app preview*. I don't see any network related calls in the debugger in Chrome. CORS is enabled. Its an Ionic 2 app (cordova).

Running the app in the emulator or on a real device works perfectly fine with the same code.

I'm using MobileFirst Platform 8.0 hosted on BlueMix.

Comment: Can you share your project that recreates this problem

Comment: I now found thise line in a blog post:
"Security checks are not run on the server-side and security challenges are not sent to the client that runs in the Mobile Browser Simulator"

Is this still true? Looks like it.

Same post says I should be able to call adapters using WLResourceRequest, so will go ahead and try that next.

Answer (score 0):

For app preview in MobileFirst 8.0 use command

```
mfpdev app preview
```

MobileFirst applications can access resources using the **WLResourceRequest** REST API.

I suggest that you will take a tour of the MobileFirst Resource request from JavaScript in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/cordova-apps/

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/resource-request/javascript/

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/bluemix/using-mobile-foundation/